# Too many images loading are slowing my loadtime, how to a feature which permits only 20 to show and another 20 when scrolled

Tags: joomla-3.x, responsive-web-design

I know how to add pages but I would like a cleaner interface that I see in other sites, such as Google Images

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? Is it a photogallery? an images portfolio site? an articles blog layout page with many articles that have their own images? a single article with many images?

Comment: It's a page with just photos, no articles. Very similar to a gallery

Answer (score 1):

Installing [Lazy Load for Joomla](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/lazy-load-for-joomla) will likely help. It's free.

Lazy Load for Joomla "saves your server bandwidth and saves your users from loading images that they never scroll to".

Alternatively you could implement a gallery extension e.g. [Event Gallery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/event-gallery) that uses AJAX or lazy loading or similar so that a minimum number of images are loaded initially.